# SQL Server Report Builder - TransactionDate value incorrectly appearing larger than the endDate value

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a value `TransactionDate` that is being pulled from a dataset and a value `endDate` that is being created as a parameter once selected by the user.

For about 98% of all my report lines, the correct result is shown accordingly, but I have a few lines that are not appropriately returning the data as intended and it is because the Report Builder is identifying certain `TransactionDates` to be larger than the `endDate`.

Parameter has already been set to a calculated field -> `FormatDateTime(Parameters!endDate.Value,DateFormat.ShortDate)`

The statement I am using that is showing me the results I am viewing to understand what is working and what isn't is:

```
=IIF((Fields!endDateCalc.Value >= Fields!TransactionDateCalc.Value), Fields!UnitSales.Value, "N/A")
```

Essentially I am concerned with understanding why this might be occurring/what I am doing to cause this to happen.

I've of course reversed the formula used that shows me the results I am looking for and reversing it to see if the line reacts, and it does. (Simply switching the `>=` to `<=`.

For example, we can say `TransactionDate` is `3/4/2019` and `endDate` is `3/25/2019`. For this line, it would return the incorrect result and present as `N/A`. This should be returning the correct `UnitSales` value for this line, but as stated it doesn't.

Whereas if `TransactionDate` was `3/12/2019` and `endDate` was still `3/25/2019`, it would return the correct `UnitSales` value.

Please let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: So it seems your logic is comparing strings, does it not? So what are the datatypes of these columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking that the comparison is taking `3/4/2019` and for some reason, taking the 4 and comparing that to the 2 in the `endDate`.  I would suggest changing the comparison to something like the following expression.

```
  =IIF((Year(CDate(Fields!endDate.Value)) >= Year(CDate(Fields!TransactionDate.Value))) 
     AND DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear, CDate(Fields!endDate.Value)) >= DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear, CDate(Fields!TransactionDate.Value)),
     Fields!UnitSales.Value, "N/A")
```

This will first compare the years of each date and then avoids any issue with conversion and simply gets the day of the year for each to compare and confirm that `endDate` is greater than `TransactionDate`.

Comment: That does return a correct result as intended for the examples above, however, if the TransactionDate is hypothetically 2/26/2019 then it will return "N/A" as the expressions value.

Comment: @AlC. And what is the end date for that hypothetical?

Comment: The same, 3/25/2019

Comment: @AlC. I'm thinking you will need to include a `CDate` around your fields in this expression to get it to work.  While testing, I can see that `2/26/2019` returns 57 for `DayOfYear` and `3/26/2019` returns 84.  I'm editing my answer with the appropriate changes.

Comment: Seems to still return the incorrect result ("N/A") on my end for: TransactionDate = 2/26/2019 and endDate = 3/25/2019 when using the above expression even with the added CDate update.

Comment: Condensing it down to just CDate in the expression seems to return what I'm looking for. Thank you for the assistance. =IIF((CDate(Fields!endDateCalc.Value) >= CDate(Fields!TransactionDateCalc.Value)),
     Fields!UnitSales.Value, "N/A")